# Is there a smart way to use different types of brackets with ANTLR

Tags: parsing, lisp, antlr4

I'm making a Lisp parser and I wanted to accept the following line:

`(defvar a [+ 2 1] )`

But not this one:

`(defvar a [+ 2 1) ]`

The solution i came up with was something like this:

`define_var: ('(' KW_DEFVAR ID expression ')' ) | ('[' KW_DEFVAR ID expression ']');`

It works, but for longer expressions this is not viable.

Comment: Your rule `define_var: ('(' KW_DEFVAR ID expression ')' ) | ('[' KW_DEFVAR ID expression ']');` will not match `(defvar a [+ 2 1] )`. Did you mean to say it matches `[ defvar a [+ 2 1] ]` instead?

Comment: yeah, of course, that's just an example of how it looks like, the main thing is that I duplicate the line and each one has a different type of bracket, that's what i'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: "yeah, of course, ..." it helps to provide the correct examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the tokens/rules in common in a sub rule like this:

```
define_var
 : '(' define_var_subrule ')'
 | '[' define_var_subrule ']'
 ;

define_var_subrule
 : KW_DEFVAR ID expression
 ;
```